# jQuery need to change only text content in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `li` elements having icon,text in each element. I want to change first li icon and text on button click. Currently it is replacing whole anchor tag content if i use `.text()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#changeicon").click(function(){
    $("#listitems li:eq(0) a span").removeClass("ic1").addClass("ic3");
    //$("#listitems li:eq(0) a").text("Icon3");//Uncomment this line and check
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  display:block;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
}
.ic1 {
  background:url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-32.png") no-repeat;
}
.ic2 {
  background:url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/navigation-set-arrows-part-one/32/Grid-32.png") no-repeat;
}
.ic3 {
  background:url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/4web-3/139/menu-32.png") no-repeat;
}
.ic4 {
  background:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/45_Menu-32.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listitems">
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <span class="ic1"></span>
            Icon1
            <span class="ic1"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <span class="ic2"></span>
            Icon2
            <span class="ic2"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="changeicon" value="Change 1 to 3">
```

Is there any way i can change the text only?

Please don't provide me something like `$("#listitems li:eq(0) a").html('<span class="ic3"></span>Icon3<span class="ic3"></span>')`? that i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't put the text in it's own span element, try this:

```js
   

 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#changeicon").click(function(){
        $("#listitems li:eq(0) a span").removeClass("ic1").addClass("ic3");
        $("#listitems li:eq(0) a").contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType === 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
  })[1].textContent = "Icon3";
        //$("#listitems li:eq(0) a").text("Icon3");//Uncomment this line and check
      });
    });
```

```css
span {
  display:block;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
}
.ic1 {
  background:url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-32.png") no-repeat;
}
.ic2 {
  background:url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/navigation-set-arrows-part-one/32/Grid-32.png") no-repeat;
}
.ic3 {
  background:url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/4web-3/139/menu-32.png") no-repeat;
}
.ic4 {
  background:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/45_Menu-32.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listitems">
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <span class="ic1"></span>
            Icon1
            <span class="ic1"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <span class="ic2"></span>
            Icon2
            <span class="ic2"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="changeicon" value="Change 1 to 3">
```

Answer (score 7):

What comes to my mind is to put the text inside some element too:

```
<li>
    <a href="">
        <span class="icon ic1"></span>
        <span class="text">Icon1</span>
        <span class="icon ic1"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And then in JS do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#changeicon").click(function(){
    $("#listitems li:eq(0) a .icon").removeClass("ic1").addClass("ic3");
    $("#listitems li:eq(0) a .text").text("Icon3");
  });
});
```

There might still be a better way to do this

Comment: Thanks for the code @TuomasK, but i need to have in the given structure only :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nodeType` property to filter only text nodes (they have `nodeType == 3`) and then use the `textContent` property to change its content. Demo:

```
$('#listitems').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3
    }).each(function(){
        this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('Icon1','Icon3');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to modify text that is not inside an tag.

You can do so using the `data` attribute of your text node :

In the current page (run your code snippet), you can do something like that :

```
document.getElementById('listitems').getElementsByTagName('li')[0].children[0].childNodes[2].data = "coucou";
```

Also you can retrieve the text node by transforming the `NodeList` to an `Array` and then use the `filter` method on it :

```
Array.from(document.getElementById('listitems').getElementsByTagName('li')[0].children[0].childNodes).filter(el => el.data.indexOf('Icon2') != -1)[0]
```

Hope it helps,

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

How about this `$("#listitems li:eq(0) a").html($("#listitems li:eq(0) a").html().replace("Icon1","Icon3"));`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#changeicon").click(function(){
    $("#listitems li:eq(0) a span").removeClass("ic1").addClass("ic3");
    $("#listitems li:eq(0) a").html($("#listitems li:eq(0) a").html().replace("Icon1","Icon3"));
    console.log($("#listitems li:eq(0) a").html());
    
    //Uncomment this line and check
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  display:block;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
}
.ic1 {
  background:url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-32.png") no-repeat;
}
.ic2 {
  background:url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/navigation-set-arrows-part-one/32/Grid-32.png") no-repeat;
}
.ic3 {
  background:url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/4web-3/139/menu-32.png") no-repeat;
}
.ic4 {
  background:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/45_Menu-32.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listitems">
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <span class="ic1"></span>
            Icon1
            <span class="ic1"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <span class="ic2"></span>
            Icon2
            <span class="ic2"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="changeicon" value="Change 1 to 3">
```